# WordPress Plugin : readme.txt is not read by WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, readme

I'm currently developing a private WordPress Plugin using [BoilerPlate](https://github.com/DevinVinson/WordPress-Plugin-Boilerplate) for the bases and [Plugin-update-checker](https://github.com/YahnisElsts/plugin-update-checker) for automatic update (without my plugin being on official WordPress repository).

Right now, I have an issue: WordPress doesn't read my `README.txt`, when I want to do an update, it should give me the changelog part of my readme.txt. It should give me this:

```
== Changelog ==

= 1.0 =
* A change since the previous version.
* Another change.

= 0.5 =
* List versions from most recent at top to oldest at bottom.
```

The problem is, this `readme.txt` and the update with the `plugin-update-checker` works perfectly on my other plugin, so I'm really lost right now.

Here's the header of my plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * The plugin bootstrap file
 *
 * This file is read by WordPress to generate the plugin information in the plugin
 * admin area. This file also includes all of the dependencies used by the plugin,
 * registers the activation and deactivation functions, and defines a function
 * that starts the plugin.
 *
 * @link              http://www.mba-multimedia.com/
 * @since             1.2
 * @package           Foo
 * Plugin Name:       Foobar
 * Plugin URI:        Foobar.com
 * Version:           3.3
 * Author:            Test
 * Author URI:        www.Mysite.org
 * License:           GPL-2.0+
 * License URI:       http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * Text Domain:       Foo
 * Domain Path:       /languages
 */
```

Tell me if you need more information, sorry for my english, and thanks.

Comment: Your code to read `readme.txt` file and where is it located in your plugin?

Comment: What do you mean about "Your code to read readme.txt" ? My readme.txt file is located to the root, the same place where my main-plugin file is located

Comment: By `readme.txt`, do you mean the `README Plugin Header Information` or a separate file that you've in your plugin directory?

Comment: I mean a separate file that I have in my plugin directory.